# How to identify if cancelled ScheduledFuture is actually not cancelled?

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, java.util.concurrent

I'm using a ScheduledExecutorService and submitting a task like that:

```
future = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(myRunnableTask, delay, timeunit)
```

However a certain event might occur after indefinite amount of time, which signals that this task is no longer needed. And so I need to cancel this task, and I am using

`boolean cancelled = future.cancel(false)` line.

After cancelling, I have to take different actions depending on whether the submitted runnable actually ran or not. And here lets first jump into Oracle Documentation and read what `cancelled` flag means:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)

> Returns: false if the task could not be cancelled, typically because it has already completed normally; true otherwise

That's all it says about the return value. Seems like the person who wrote this text line was uncertain about `false` return value here, but I think I can take it.

Lets now focus on the case, when it returns `true`. There are two possibilities here:

1. The task was actually cancelled and runnable never ran.
2. The runnable is in the process of running and thus cannot be cancelled. (unless I do some thread interrupting logic, which I don't really want to do)

I am okay with both cases occurring, but I want to KNOW which one actually occurred and take actions accordingly. If the runnable is in the process, then I am okay with it finishing it's job, I want to wait for it's completion and then do one thing. But if it was cancelled and never going to run at all, I want to do another thing.

Can you please recommend an approach to this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing something like this for this issue. Source code and some unit tests can be found at https://github.com/nuzayats/cancellabletaskexecutor

```
public class CancellableTaskExecutor {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService es;
    private final Logger log;

    /**
     * For a unit test to replicate a particular timing
     */
    private final Runnable hookBetweenCancels;

    public CancellableTaskExecutor(ScheduledExecutorService es, Logger log) {
        this(es, log, () -> {
            // nop
        });
    }

    // For unit tests
    CancellableTaskExecutor(ScheduledExecutorService es, Logger log, Runnable hookBetweenCancels) {
        this.es = es;
        this.log = log;
        this.hookBetweenCancels = hookBetweenCancels;
    }

    public Execution schedule(Runnable task, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
        CancellableRunnable runnable = new CancellableRunnable(task);
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = es.schedule(runnable, delay, unit);
        return new Execution(future, runnable);
    }

    public class Execution {

        private final ScheduledFuture<?> future;
        private final CancellableRunnable runnable;

        private Execution(ScheduledFuture<?> future, CancellableRunnable runnable) {
            this.future = future;
            this.runnable = runnable;
        }

        /**
         * @return true when the task has been successfully cancelled and it's guaranteed that
         * the task won't get executed. otherwise false
         */
        public boolean cancel() {
            boolean cancelled = runnable.cancel();
            hookBetweenCancels.run();

            // the return value of this call is unreliable; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55922874/3591946
            future.cancel(false);

            return cancelled;
        }
    }

    private class CancellableRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final AtomicBoolean cancelledOrStarted = new AtomicBoolean();
        private final Runnable task;

        private CancellableRunnable(Runnable task) {
            this.task = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!cancelledOrStarted.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                return; // cancelled, forget about the task
            }
            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.log(Level.WARNING, "Uncaught Exception", e);
            }
        }

        boolean cancel() {
            return cancelledOrStarted.compareAndSet(false, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I remember we found a way to simplify things and managed to avoid this problem completely. But your answer looks better than the previous one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish your goal with the following:

- A `Set<Runnable>` that keeps track of `Runnable`s that have begun execution by the thread pool.
- A `Map<ScheduledFuture<?>, Runnable>` that maps a `ScheduledFuture<?>` to its respective `Runnable`.

  - After scheduling the task, you should immediately add the `ScheduledFuture` and its respective `Runnable` to the `Map`.
  - If this insertion into the `Map` is performed atomically with scheduling the task itself, then you can avoid the edge case that the `ScheduledFuture` was never added to the `Map` even after it was cancelled.

I recommend changing your [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), which will allow you to override its [`beforeExecute(Thread, Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Runnable)) method; this method is invoked immediately before the task is run by the pool after it has already been assigned a thread that will execute the task.

When overriding this method, you can add the `Runnable` to your `Set<Runnable>`.

Then, when a `ScheduledFuture` is cancelled, you can call `set.contains(map.get(future))`, which tells you if the `Runnable` (that the `ScheduledFuture` maps to) was executed.

---

Note that your `Set<Runnable>` and `Map<ScheduledFuture<?>, Runnable>` implementations may have to be made thread-safe to avoid possible race conditions.